# Dynamic way to get a list of ticked checkboxes on a php generated page

Tags: javascript, php, button, checkbox, html-table

I've got a webpage that returns a dynamic number of rows from a mysql db, which is output to the webpage via  table, of which the first column is a checkbox via the following code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $id = $row['circuit_id'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\"><input name=\"checkbox[]\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox[]\" value=" . $row['circuit_id'] . "></td>";
        if ($row['status_name'] == 'Disconnected') {
            echo "<td><font color=\"red\">" . $row['status_name'] . "</font></td>";
            } else {
            echo "<td>" . $row['status_name'] . "</td>";
            };
    echo "<td>" . $row['circuit_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['circuit_appID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['circuit_appID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"circuits_modify.php?id=".$row['circuit_id']."\"><img src=\"images/icons/application_edit.png \"></a></td>"; 
    echo "<td><a href=\"circuit_notes.php?id=".$row['circuit_id']."\" onclick=\"return popitup('circuit_notes.php?id=$id')\"><img src=\"images/icons/note_add.png \"></a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

below this data presentation, I've added a few HTML buttons (one of which is shown below) that will allow the user to do 'mass' updates on the shown data, in this particular case to change the status from one state to another via the checkbox selection.

```
    echo "<table align=\"center\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Set status to Migrated for selected records</td><td><a href=\"update_selected_records.php\"><img src=\"images/icons/application_edit.png \"></a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
```

Is there a way to get the list of checkboxes that have been selected without changing everything to forms, and using a simple html based button to submit the request to the server?

I've been looking for an online solution for something like this via javascript but haven't managed to find anything that matches what I need.

Thanks

I've tried to piece together a few bits and pieces to get where I need to be, but am not making much progress at all, here's the current code:

```
    var obj = {}
    $('#click').on('click', function() {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
            var name = $(this).attr('id');
            obj[name] = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
        });
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) { 
        alert(key + ' : ' + value); 
    });
        console.log(obj);
    });​
```

how do I get the list of 'true' ie. ticked boxes into a string and update the button with a 'new' url?

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: typing all those escape characters seems painful to me

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has the option to select all checkboxes and submit them in the background via AJAX..

jQuery Selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

jQuery AJAX: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Good luck and hope this helps you!